# Notification implementation in swift

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, distance

I'm implementing notification using FCM so  when the  app is in foreground I'm getting notification but after termination of app notification are not coming.   I have already saved latitude and longitude  and another I'm getting from api then I'm finding distance between two points if that point lies between 10 miles then I will show that notification.

Here's a code for that

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    FirebaseApp.configure()

    attemptRegisterForNotifications(application: application)
}


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {

    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
    parseReceivedNotification(userInfo: userInfo)
}


func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification:      UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

    self.applicationGlobal = UIApplication.shared

    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
   
    parseReceivedNotification(userInfo: userInfo)
    completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.alert)
}


func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    self.applicationGlobal = UIApplication.shared

    parseReceivedNotification(userInfo: userInfo)
    
    completionHandler()
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
   
      self.applicationGlobal = application
       parseReceivedNotification(userInfo: userInfo)
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)

}
```

**here's a parser for message :**

```
func parseReceivedNotification(userInfo:[AnyHashable : Any])  {
    var dataUserinfo1 = userInfo//try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: dd.data(using: .utf8)!, options: []) as! [String:Any]
    var  latitude :  Double = 0.0
    var  longitude : Double = 0.0
    var dataUservalue  =  [[String : Any]]()
    
    global_userInfo = [:]
    
    if !dataUserinfo1.isEmpty {
       
        
        var exdate:String = ""
        let page = dataUserinfo1["page"] as? String ?? "0"
        let calendar = Calendar.current

        guard   let dataUserStorevalue = dataUserinfo1["msg"]  else { return }
    
        let data = (dataUserStorevalue as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        do {
            if let dataUservalueget  = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options : .allowFragments) as? [[String : Any]]
            {
                dataUservalue =  dataUservalueget
                print(dataUservalue)
               
            } else {
                print("bad json")
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
        
        
        var storingTempDistrance = 0
        
        for dataUserinfo in dataUservalue {
              
            var str: String =   dataUserinfo["m"] as! String

              let items = str.components(separatedBy: "--") //take the one array for split the string
           
            
            var heading: String = items [0]
           
            var  message = items[1]
            latitude =  Double(items[2])!
            longitude = Double(items[3])!
            var aqivalue = items[4]
```

**// Already saved latitude and longitude and another I'm getting  from api**

```
            let savlat = Double(UserDefaultUtilities.getLatitudeOrLongitude(key: CommonUtilities.LATITUDE))
            let savLong = Double(UserDefaultUtilities.getLatitudeOrLongitude(key: CommonUtilities.LONGITUDE))
      
            var distance = mesaureDistance(startX : latitude , startY : longitude, endX : savLong! , endY : savlat! )
             
    
            
            if (distance < 10)
            {
           self.notification = NotificationObject(heading: heading, message: message, aqi: aqivalue)
                
                
                
                var notificationArray = UserDefaultUtilities.NotificatiionsArray
                 notificationArray.append(self.notification)
         
               
                CommonUtilities.showWeatherNotificationWithUserInfo(notification: notification,  userInfo: global_userInfo )
                
                
            }
            
        }

 
    }
 

}
```

// here's  a function to show notification

```
public static func showWeatherNotificationWithUserInfo(notification:NotificationObject , userInfo:[AnyHashable : Any]){
    let identifier =  "12321"
    var userInfoFinal = userInfo
   
     userInfoFinal["parsed"] = true
    
   
    let notificationContent = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    notificationContent.title = notification.heading
    notificationContent.body = notification.message
    notificationContent.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
    notificationContent.userInfo = userInfoFinal

 
    
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier, content: notificationContent, trigger: nil)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) {(error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error in setting reminder for drug: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that when your app is terminated, your latitude & longitude are updating?

Comment: I have already stored latitude and longitude in variable and I'm not concerned on updating values of these.